# Issue with Section Transitions using Velocity.js and JQuery ~ Glitching Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, velocity.js

Aloha!

I'm having a performance issue with a page running velocity.js transitions.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dolanbrendan12/w3fdvru4/1/) - Click anywhere on the container to change screens.

All is running perfectly smoothly advancing to a next screen, as well as navigating backward via the back button. *However,* after I have navigated backward and try to advance forwards again, I get a glitch in the animation.

Here's the jquery I'm using:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
$(this).parent().fadeOut(1000).nextAll().slice(0, 2).fadeIn(1000); //hide parent (section) and show the next one
$(this).prevAll().velocity('transition.slideDownOut', {
    stagger: 250
}); //stagger transition out all of .next's previous siblings
$(this).parent().next().children().velocity({
    delay: 750
}).velocity('transition.slideDownIn', {
    stagger: 250,
    backwards: true
}); //stagger transition in all of the next section's children after a delay });
```

You can see the back button's script as well on the jsfiddle.

`.elmt` is set to `opacity: 0` to make sure they are hidden initially.

The second two screens, `div-3` and `div-4`, are initially set to `display:none` so that they don't need to load when landing on the page at `div-1`.

Can anyone see what may be causing the problem?

Thank you, and happy weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove:

```
backwards: true
```

Read about this properties [Docs](http://velocityjs.org/#uiPack),
and here you have example what backwards do:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/fEKsw).

Comment: Great! Thanks. I wasn't expecting that to be the problem. However, without `backwards` the animated items won't reveal in the order I'd like, with the bottom element leading. `backwards: true` took care of that. Any suggestions?